# Change character automatically whilst being input in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble working this out. Basically my program has a standard input, I want to modify this so if the user enters a space it automatically replaces it with a / whilst they're typing. I have no idea how i'd even go about doing this or if it is even possible so I am grateful for any help either way.

Comment: This is possible but is going to require a potentially platform-specific library, so it would help to specify which OS you are programming for.

Comment: Standard input says text only. If you can't do the same to a text file, then you can't do it with the standard input alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to turn off echoing of the characters typed and then echo them yourself after validating them, replacing characters as necessary.  There are different ways to do that for different operating systems (e.g. Linux vs. Windows), and even more unfortunately, that can mean taking control of the entire screen just for this simple function since the backspace/delete key would need to be handled properly (even over multiple lines if necessary).  In short, you're taking control away from the user while making yourself responsible for the common functionality that a user would expect, which makes things rather difficult because you can't know how certain terminals behave, not to mention issues with locales.  It's easier just to replace the characters yourself after the input is received or issue an error message, depending on your purpose and specific use-case.

Edit: [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) is cross-platform, so you might try that if you're still interested.  It's easier than coding for specific platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Some really good information. Will give it a go and let you know how I get on :).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you want to do manipulation of the text on the console like that, you're going to need a library such as ncurses.